# Find Value on Array by Index on VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, arrays, indexing

How to find a value on an array by it's index on VB.Net?

```
// INDEX:                       0    1    2    3    4
Dim DataArray(4) as Integer = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}
```

Then, I randomize a number from 0 to 4. For example, when I got 3, then I will get `D` value on the array based on the randomize number. How can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just access the value by having the index after the array name

```
Dim letter As String = DataArray(YourRandNumber)
```

Also there is a problem with your array, DataArray is declared as an integer array but storing alphabet, so you should change it to

```
Dim DataArray(5) As String = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}
```

or

```
Dim DataArray(5) As Char= {"A"c, "B"c, "C"c, "D"c, "E"c}
```

The little c after "A" means it is a character

Answer (score 1):

By what I think you mean, you should have some code like (*for example in a console-style form*):

```
Randomize()
Console.writeline(DataArray(math.ceiling(Rnd() * [upperbound)))
```

This will return a random character.